# pfsense live cd and boot options

Tags: boot, pfsense, bsd

I donwloaded pfsense live cd 2.1.3 and now I want to run pfsense from an usb cdrom drive.

It loads a while and than crahses with "unable to  mount ..."

I know I have to choose boot option `3` in order to boot from an usb cdrom but I don't see this menu.

[image]

The computer just boots. Do I need to press a specfic key to bring up this menu or is this maybe missing on the current iso?

Comment: Are you sure about that? Isn't it just "too fast"? Also, I don't think that you need the USB device option.

Comment: @MichelZ - I sure need it - https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Boot_Troubleshooting#Booting_from_USB - Anyway I solved it, it was not too fast, it only took forever.

Comment: Thanks for the Info. Could you post an answer on *how* you solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it,

to boot from USB Drive, you need boot option number #3

https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Boot_Troubleshooting#Booting_from_USB

> Booting from USB
>
> If the boot stops with a mountroot error while booting off the live
> CD, usually with USB CD/DVD drives, escape to the loader prompt and
> run the following:  set kern.cam.boot_delay="10000"  boot
>
> On 2.0 this is on the boot menu - option #3 to boot from USB devices.

I just thought the prompt would come very early, like grub or something. But it turned out I had to wait about five minutes  (old hardware with USB 1.1 only) for it to show up. And it vanishes after 10 seconds, I think I just missed it the first few tries.

Comment: Great work solved my exact same problem